# Python: finding leftmost non-zero in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

say I have this list of list

```
listlist = [[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1]]
```

and a empty dict()

```
answer = dict()
```

and say I want to find the leftmost non-zero in each list such that I can save the index of that non-zero number into a dictionary like:

```
for list in listlist: #(this is how the first iteration would look like:)

answer[0] = 3
```

next iteration

```
answer[1] = 2
```

next iteration

```
answer[2] = 0
```

I am pretty new at programming, so excuse me if it is trivial, I have tried different stuff and it is hard to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming only `0`s and `1`s this should work

```
i = 0
for mylist in listlist:
  answer[i] = mylist.index(1)
  i += 1
```

I recommend that you do not name your list `list`, that overrides some functionality.  I prefer to default to the variable name `mylist`

Comment: Straight forward answer for a beginner. ```enumerate``` can come later.

Comment: @twall yep, and knowing python, there's probably even a module somewhere that does this exact thing for you

Answer (score 8):

If it's only ever `0`s and `1`s just do something like,

```
>>> answer = {i: lst.index(1) for i, lst in enumerate(listlist)}
>>> answer
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 0}
```

Also, don't use `list` as a variable name since it will mask `list` built-in.

Comment: nice dict generator with `enumerate()` you should probably explain it though

Answer (score 2):

```
listlist = [[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1]]
answer = dict()
for idx,alist in enumerate(listlist):
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        if alist[i] > 0:
            answer[idx] = i
```